# Mitel 3300 - replacing a phone (one died, swapping for another)

Tags: voip, mitel

I have to replace someones phone on a Mitel 3300 and we just took over this system so a bit new to us.

do I just change the mac address in the users account info or is it more complicated then that?

thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone, Wish I would of seen Steve's note first :), I ended up replacing the mac address after having to do a few things in multi-line set key assignment then I was able to just change the Mac on the user account info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the help on feature access codes. One of the codes is a Set Replacement code. I think you can plug in the new set and enter the replacement code followed by the extension of that device to have it switched automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What Steve said. Or, as you say, you can replace the MAC Address in the user's details. Make sure to also update what model of phone it is, if different.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the discussion underneath [How to remove static IP from Mitel 5312 and enable DHCP](https://serverfault.com/questions/204833/how-to-remove-static-ip-from-mitel-5312-and-enable-dhcp) might help, depending exactly how your controller/users/phones are configured -- from memory, just editing the MAC should be enough, assuming it's the same model handset!