# How to remove static IP from Mitel 5312 and enable DHCP

Tags: dhcp, voip, mitel

I'm not sure this is the right forum for this question -- although I'm confident I'll be told if not! -- but I've read the fine manual (at least, such a manual as I have), I've googled and I cannot get any insight into where to even start solving this problem.

I have a bunch of Mitel 5312 handsets, talking to a 3300 ICP controller. Some handsets are at a remote location, get an address from my DHCP server over there, and use the Mitel "Teleworker" extension to connect in over the Internet. The remaining handsets were set up with static IPs by a BT-supplied engineer, on the same subnet as the ICP itself. So far, so good.

I have one remaining teleworker licence, and need to move a handset from the home location to the remote. I've managed to boot it and configure teleworker, but I cannot for the life of me see where I tell it to forget its static IP, and make a DHCP request.

Any ideas? Should I be looking on the controller, or holding magic combinations of buttons on the handset itself?

**EDIT**: Following some advice from Robert, below, I've broken out a spare device and reassigned the profile for this user's extension to the MAC of the new phone, and a new profile to the old MAC. Unfortunately this still doesn't get me anywhere -- the new handset now asks for the teleworker install password.

I suspect I'm going to have to get a Mitel engineer involved here, since I've never been given that password... Unless anyone has any great ideas?

Comment: It is a little worrying that I asked 1 of the only 2 other questions tagged "mitel", and the remaining one had no answers... Oh well, I can but hope :-)

Comment: Well I'm not sure I've given you a "good" answer but at least I've had a swing at it for you!

Comment: Any attempt is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have a MAS server? I think you can set someone's teleworker password through the admin console@ http://<INTERNALipaddress>/server-manager - you will need the MAS admin password though.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean MSL - and yep, I eventually found the teleworker password in there. So, largely sorted - although I never answered the original question, I do now have a working teleworker handset...

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

hold the 2 arrow keys(up/down)
keep the up key and pres  2 3 4
after that you come in the configuration scroll with the # to modify static value and press 0 ...

Answer (score 1):

A guess, to be fair, but what happens if you remove the MAC address of the telephone device from the extension number details (User Configuration I think) in the 3300 system admin tools, so that the phone has to be registered again prior to use? This won't delete the telephone number/user, just the association between their number and that device.

Comment: The device screen displays "USE Superkey TO SEND PIN". On rebooting the device, it still has the old static IP -- it pings, but shows as "Out of service" on the system admin interface. So I guess my next step is to find the PIN! (Although, pasting the MAC address back in and rebooting the phone also puts it back as it was)

Comment: @jimbo The pin should be the device phone number preceded by a default sequence of characters, I think by default it's ***ExtensionNumber, e.g. ***1234 then press and hold superkey for a few seconds. It's interesting (and annoying) that doesn't clear a static IP address, I was told that should reset a phone device to factory settings. sorry about that!